# is it possible to send big array over UDP?

Tags: udp, stm32, lwip, stm32f7

i want to send large array (array[1600])  with stm32f767 and lan8720a with udp.
when my array biger than 1319 byte the mcu can not send(i don't receive anything with my terminal software(UdpClientServer.exe) )
my array is full of 'A' character

'''

void MY_UdpSendData(void)
{

```
uint16_t i=0;
uint16_t BufferSize=0;

struct pbuf *p;

while(array[i]=='A')
{
    i++;
    BufferSize++;
}

p = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, BufferSize, PBUF_RAM); 
 pbuf_take(p, array, sizeof(array[0])*BufferSize);

udp_send(udp_send_pcb, p);

pbuf_free(p);
```

}

//////////while(1)

while (1)
{

```
    MX_LWIP_Process();
    
    cntr++;
    if(cntr > 200000)
    {
        cntr=0;
        MY_UdpSendData();
        
    }
```

}

'''

Comment: No. The generally accepted payload limit for UDP is 534 bytes. WIthin a LAN you may be able to achive 1260 or whatever will fit into an IP MTU, but you can't rely on it, and any UDP datagram that gets segmented may get lost altogether (as indeed they all may).

Comment: what should i do? I need to be able to send data over 1600 bytes with udp....